# JavaScript FileReader using a lot of memory

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I have a problem with my little project.
Every time the music player is loading new songs into playlist or you are pressing a song on the list to get it playing, it's using a lot of memory, and it stays high until you shut it down. I think its every time I'm using the filereader API that it uses memory, but I'm also loading ID3 information with the `jDataView.js` script which I also think is taking a lot of memory.

Do you guys have any suggestion, to load,store and play songs with the `FileReader`, without taking up memory? I've tried to see if it was possible to clear the fileReader after using, but I couldn't find anything. I've only tested in Chrome.

UPDATE: 
I have tested my project,and found out, that its when im trying to load the datastring it takes up memory.

```
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if(typeof(e) != "undefined"){
        e.pause();
    }
    e = new Audio();
    e.src = evt.target.result; // evt.target.result call takes the memory
    e.setAttribute("type", songs[index]["file"].type);
    e.play();
    e.addEventListener("ended", function() { LoadAudioFile(index + 1) }, false);
};
```

Is there another way to load the data into the audio element?

Comment: When you have such a problem, the first thing to do is to see where the memory is used. Have a look at Chrome's memory profiler : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not because of `FileReader` but because you are making the `src` attribute of audio element a 1.33 * mp3filesize string. So instead of the `src` attribute being a nice short url pointing to a mp3 resource, it's the whole mp3 file in base64 encoding. It's a wonder your browser didn't crash.

You should not read the file with `FileReader` at all, but create a blob URL from the file and use that as src.

```
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

//Src will be like "blob:http%3A//stackoverflow.com/d13eb575-4863-4f86-8727-6400119f4afc"
//A very short string that is pointing to the original resource in hard drive

var src = url.createObjectURL( mp3filereference );

audioElement.src = src;
```

Comment: But when im using this method, the file needs to be on the server, right? This will take up alot of space to store each file for every user who using it. Isn't it possible to store the file in the browser?

Comment: @QuakeDK no, this is for local files on users computer, `mp3filereference` is equal to `songs[index]["file"]` in your code. If this were from a server, one would just use `src` from the server without reading any files at all..

Comment: @QuakeDK I think I understand what you mean now, no it doesn't place the file on any server, it creates a `blob url` that points to the file in users computer. It's the modern version of `file:///` urls.

Comment: Wauw, now its blazing fast! :D Thanks!

Comment: @QuakeDK around here we say thanks by accepting answers and upvoting them ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry ;) there you go. Just another little thing. When i was using the filereader api, i could load ID3 tags from the file. But now when im only having a `blob URL` how can i load it then? i've tried by using the src link, but that dosn't work. (using [this API](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader))

Comment: @QuakeDK yeah you can use FileReader to read id3 tags, the problem in your post was the huge string being the `src` of an audio element.

Comment: Wow I didn't even know this was possible for all these years. This deserves way more upvotes than it currently has.